# i tried to add movie in selected-movie class, but i dont understand whats wrong with my code

Tags: angular, typescript, shopping-cart

i have cart-movie.service.ts this service create addMovies method for add movies in selected-movie class, but i don't understand how i should do that

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="col-2" *ngFor="let movie of moviesList" (click)="addMovies(movie)">
      <div class="movie">
        {{ movie.attributes.title }}
        <img [src]="movie.thumbnails.small">
        <p><strong>Duration:</strong> {{ movie.attributes.duration | formatime}}mn</p>
        <div class="details">
          <p><strong>Director:</strong><br> {{ movie.attributes.director }}</p>
          <p><strong>the actors:</strong><br>{{ movie.attributes.actors }}</p>
          <p><strong>the release year:</strong><br>{{ movie.attributes.year }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <h1 class="col-12">
      Movies Selected
    </h1>
    <div class="col-12 selected-movie">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MoviesService, Movie } from './shared/services/movies.services';
import { CartMoviesService } from './shared/services/cart-movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'app-entretien';
  moviesList: Movie[];
  moviesSelected: Movie[];

  currentPage: number = 0;

  constructor(private moviesService: MoviesService, private cartMoviesService: CartMoviesService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.moviesService.getList(1, 20).subscribe(data => {
      this.moviesList = data.content;
    });
    this.cartMoviesService.addMovies(this.movie);
  }
```

I did call the service here, I don't know what argument to give it

**cart-movies.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartMoviesService {

  public cart = [];
  movie: any;

  constructor() { }

  addMovies(movie) {
    this.cart.push(movie);
    alert(movie + 'was added to cart');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app.component.html doesnt magically known that the method is in the cartMoviesService service. It works the same as in the ts file. Try to add it so it understands where to get the method:

```
(click)="addMovies(movie)"
```

Change it too:

```
(click)"cartMoviesService.addMovies(movie)"
```

Now you should be able to use the created method :)

Comment: thanks for you help, when i click on a movie it returns me [object object] why ?

Comment: Try to use console.log(movie, ' movie was added to cart'); instead of the alert, then when you open developer tools in your browser you can see the object in your browser. If you use alert( movie + ' was added to cart'). It will try to make 1 text/string of it which is why you see [object object].

Comment: undefined " movie was added to cart" this is what i have in my console,

Comment: Is it when you clicked in your application on a movie? Or is it when the page is loaded? The app.component.ts ngOnInit calls the addmovies method as well and I dont see this.movie defined anywhere in the code. So that is where the undefined comes from I think. Try to console log this.movie in the ngOnInit to confirm this, good luck :) .

Comment: its happens when i'm clicked on movie, in service you have movie declared but i don't think the right way how to report ? in app.component.ts I have moviesSelected can i use that ?

Comment: Well its hard for me to know the exact answer, because I am not sure what response you get from getList(1,20) and what your expected behaviour is. Can you make a stackblitz example?

Comment: @Richard You defined movie in cartMoviesService, so use this.cartMoviesService.movie in your ngOnInit. In cartMoviesService change movie: any; to movie: any = 'this is a test'; And the error should be gone and you should be able to see "this is a test" in your console.

Answer (score 0):

ok i change the addMovies Method,

```
 addMovies(movie: Movies) { 
    this.cart.push(movie); console.log(movie);
```

}

and now i have object in my console :)

Comment: now in app.component.ts file in ngOnInit the addMovie An argument for 'movie' was not provided. whats wrong